# Get current month birthday list form employee table

Tags: mysql

I have an employee table with dob. Every month i want the list of current month birthday list.
I want the query for the current month employee birthday list.  The dob file date like this '31-01-1986' and so on. Please help me to get this.

Comment: Why are you storing a date in a non-ANSI standard format?

Comment: To chime in on @FreshPrinceOfSO's point. Store date's as a `date` datatype and you will save yourself a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `dob` column contains values like `'31-01-1986'`, it must be a string datatype rather than a temporal one.  This makes it difficult (and slow) to perform date operations such as you desire; you may be better off doing a pure string manipulation instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee
WHERE  CAST(SUBSTRING(dob, 4, 2) AS UNSIGNED) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

I recommend that you convert your table to use an appropriate temporal datatype, such as [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html):

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD COLUMN new_dob DATE AFTER dob;
UPDATE employee SET new_dob = STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d-%m-%Y');
ALTER TABLE employee DROP COLUMN dob, CHANGE new_dob dob DATE;
```

(Remember also to adjust indexes, as desired).

Note that you will accordingly need to update your application code to work with `DATE` literals, including the previous statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee
WHERE  MONTH(dob) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
WHERE month(dob) = month(now)
```

Comment: Would be nice if OP's date was stored as a date.

Comment: I am fairly certain mySQL will perform an implicit conversion to a date from a string.   SQL server definitely does..

Comment: Prove it to me please.

Comment: @Sparky: It will only do that if the string is a [valid date literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html), which is not the case here.